# How to bind dictionary with bitmap to combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, combobox, bitmap

I've a problem binding a `Dictionary<string, Bitmap>` to my `combobox`.
The `Bitmaps` are saved in the resource file.

This could loads the items in the combobox:

```
ComboBoxLanguage.ItemsSource = Languages;
ComboBoxLanguage.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
ComboBoxLanguage.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
ComboBoxLanguage.SelectedValue = Settings.Default.language;
```

This is my dictionary:

```
Languages = new Dictionary<string, Bitmap>
{
    { "en-US", Properties.Resources.US},
    {"de-DE", Properties.Resources.DE}
};
```

But my `ComboBox` only shows `Sysytem.Drawing.Bitmap`

Can somebody help me?

Comment: You should use `BitmapSource` for bitmaps in WPF (instead of WinForms' `Bitmap`). Then you'll have to set the ComboBox's `ItemTemplate` to a DataTemplate with an `Image` control that uses the `Value` property as its `Source`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to use `ObservableCollection` and make wrapper class.

```
public class ComboBoxData
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

In view model you should specify a list of combobox elements.

```
public ObservableCollection<ComboBoxData> Languages { get; set; }
public View()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Languages = new ObservableCollection<ComboBoxData>()
                          {
                              new MyComboboxData(){Path = "Image1.jpg", Text = "Text1"},
                              new MyComboboxData(){Path = "Image2.jpg", Text = "Text2"}
                          };

        this.DataContext = this;
}
```

And in xaml bind your combobox to this collection.

```
<ComboBox Name="ComboBoxLanguage" ItemsSource="{Binding Languages}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```